# nested for loop in R, where the second index counts inside the first one

Tags: r, loops

I have for example a datset like this:

```
data <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,2,2,3,4,5,5,"a","a","b","a","a","a","b"), nrow = 7, ncol = 2, byrow = F))

X1  X2
 1  a
 2  a
 2  b
 3  a
 4  a
 5  a
 5  b
```

then I add another variable "tag", initially set to 0.

```
data$tag <- 0

X1  X2  tag
 1  a   0
 2  a   0
 2  b   0
 3  a   0
 4  a   0
 5  a   0
 5  b   0
```

I'd like to have "tag" equal to 1 for each row that is repeated, like:

```
 X1  X2  tag
     1  a   0
     2  a   1
     2  b   1
     3  a   0
     4  a   0
     5  a   1
     5  b   1
```

I used the followed code:

```
for (i in data$X1) {
  for (j in 1:length(data$X1)) {
    if (j==2) {data$tag[j] <- 1}
  }
}
```

but it doesn't work like I would like to. I'd like the second loop (j) to work **inside** the previous one in order to obtain what I want, where j starts from 1 every time X1 changes.
How can I manage it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Note that if you are considering duplicated rows, rather than values in the `X1` column, then adapt @Ronak Shah's answer to: `data$tag <- as.integer(duplicated(data) | duplicated(data, fromLast=TRUE))`. For the current data, there are no duplicates by row, but there are duplicated values in the `X1` and `X2` columns individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `duplicated` from both the ends in base R :

```
data$tag <- as.integer(duplicated(data$X1) | 
                       duplicated(data$X1, fromLast = TRUE))
data

#  X1 X2 tag
#1  1  a   0
#2  2  a   1
#3  2  b   1
#4  3  a   0
#5  4  a   0
#6  5  a   1
#7  5  b   1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `ave`

```
within(
  data,
  tag <- +(ave(X1, X1, FUN = length) > 1)
)
```

which gives

```
  X1 X2 tag
1  1  a   0
2  2  a   1
3  2  b   1
4  3  a   0
5  4  a   0
6  5  a   1
7  5  b   1
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%  
     add_count(X1) %>%
     mutate(n = +(n > 1))
```